# What are the differences of +python and -python in vim

Tags: python, vim

Lost of posts say that `+python` is required in `vim --version` to support python. But I get `-python` in the version string. I tried the [VimOLE](http://www.vim.org/download.php) and also the [Cream (for Vim)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cream/), they both show `-python`. How to get `+python` in the Vim version and what is the different between them? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `+` or `-` in the `:version` output describes which features have (or not) been compiled into Vim. It is correct that `+python` is required to use the Python integration into Vim.

Note that (especially on Windows), it says `+python/dyn`, which means it dynamically loads the Python interpreter. For that to work, Python (in the matching version, see later in the `:version` output where it says `/nodefaultlib:python27.lib`) must be installed, too.

I can't say why you don't have Python in your builds; usually, this is enabled. If all else fails (or to support a different Python version that you may have), compiling Vim yourself is an option.

Comment: To clarify this though, in case OP is confused: `+python` is needed to use plugins written using Python. It's not, of course, needed in order to use vim to write Python code; even Python syntax highlighting will work without it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, `+python` is necessary for omnicompletion, though.